How to import Maya CV curves into Blender?
I'm having trouble trying to import a CV curve from Maya into Blender. I have tried .obj format with no result, ie nothing appears in the outliner, .fbx, which gives a series of empties, not a curve and also tried saving as a .abc file (alembic), which imports as hair or fur in the outliner, but nothing appears in the viewport. The other issue is scale, as Maya works in centimetres and Blender in metres, so I tried setting the import scale to 100 to hopefully account for this. For the .fbx import, I have to scale massively to see the empties after doing this, so adjusting the scale on import doesn't seem to be working in the way I want. Basically the import doesn't seem to understand this is a curve at all.
Could anyone help with this or is it just not possible?
Thanks so much,
Maja


Bezier curve import/export has traditionally been rare, if not impossible altogether in Blender. Only recently has the .Obj importer received support for dealing with bezier curves. Wouldn't be surprised if failed or even if Maya wasn't exporting the curve at all. Have you tried importing back into Maya and testing if the curve even survives the round trip?

Thank you for the good suggestion. I can export and reimport to Maya perfectly using .fbx and .abc files. The .obj export/reimport does not work at all and nothing appears in the Maya outliner. Unfortunately the .fbx and .abc files don't seem to import to Blender as curves. Do I give up on this?

I can also get a .usd file to reimport to Maya, so Maya is correctly exporting fbx, abc and usd files. They just don't seem to import into Blender though- abc and usd files import as fur/hair and fbx as empties.  Sigh...

As far as I know non of the Blender importers support curves. If this is a one off thing, and you don't have too many curves or too many points, maybe you can perhaps convert your curve to a mesh, conserving only the position of the bezier points and bezier handles, import that, then convert it to a curve in Blender, or manually recreate the curve using those points. If there are too many, it sounds like something that could perhaps be scripted.

Thanks, I think I'll wait until we have the option to extract the curve from the structure within Blender, rather than trying to make the import from Maya work. Thanks so much for your help!
